# Two sql servers how to synchronize second one

Tags: sql-server

There is sql server database and it'a a source, there are some views available. On the other side there is second sql server where i need to create tables reflecting those views. The key thing is to have same data on second sql server. Of course if there are any updates on source in views, second sql server should take those updates. What is the best easiest approach to do so? I was thinking first of all to make a link to source sql server using studio but what next? Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into SSIS, you can write logic for data transfer in packages and scheduled them to run at time intervals as required to synchronize data between servers.

Comment: [Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication?view=sql-server-2017) looks suitable this case

Comment: Is there any tutorial showing how to implement that? Note that we do not have any chances to configure source,we just have access to its views

Comment: I agree replication is probably the best way forward here. If you're not the DBA, then speak to the DBA and get them to set it up